# MySql join statements returning duplicate data

Tags: mysql, join

I have a fully normalised database and am running queries through mySql. One of the queries required is to return materials required as well as any associated with a job. I need a result of the following 2 queries combined into one select statement(each in a separate row and ideally making use of joins). This is explained better below:

```
SELECT m.Material_Name
FROM project_materials pm,materials m
WHERE pm.Fitting_ID =  m.Fitting_ID
AND pm.Project_ID = '2';
```

Which gives me:

```
Timber
Bricks
```

And this:

```
SELECT sjt.Job_Name
FROM project_staff ps, staff_job_type sjt
WHERE ps.Staff_job_ID = sjt.Staff_job_ID
AND ps.Project_ID = '2';
;
```

Which gives me:

```
Brick Layer
Project manager
```

I tried  to **combine** them together into one here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Material_Name, sjt.Job_Name
FROM project_materials pm, materials m, project_staff ps, staff_job_type sjt, projects p
WHERE p.Project_ID = ps.Project_ID
AND p.Project_ID = pm.Project_ID
AND pm.Fitting_ID =  m.Fitting_ID
AND ps.Staff_job_ID = sjt.Staff_job_ID
AND pm.Project_ID = '2';
```

Which didn't work out well at all since I am getting values which are repeating. I.E. the reply from the database is as follows:

```
Timber, Brick Layer
Timber, Project manager
Bricks, Brick Layer
Bricks, Project manager
```

Which results in a reply which keeps getting worse as the data grows!

I also tried using JOIN but got the same result. Here's the code I tried:

```
SELECT Material_Name, Job_Name
FROM projects INNER JOIN project_staff ON projects.Project_ID = project_staff.Project_ID
              INNER JOIN project_materials ON project_materials.Project_ID = projects.Project_ID
              INNER JOIN materials ON materials.Fitting_ID = project_materials.Fitting_ID
              INNER JOIN staff_job_type ON staff_job_type.Staff_job_ID = project_staff.Staff_job_ID
WHERE project_materials.Project_ID = '2'
;
```

Inner, left,right or no text in front of the join doesn't make a difference.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post

***EDIT***
I want something like this:

```
SELECT m.Material_Name
FROM project_materials pm,materials m
WHERE pm.Fitting_ID =  m.Fitting_ID
AND pm.Project_ID = '2'
UNION
SELECT sjt.Job_Name
FROM project_staff ps, staff_job_type sjt
WHERE ps.Staff_job_ID = sjt.Staff_job_ID
AND ps.Project_ID = '2';
;
```

But instead of union, I want it in a separate column

Comment: Not sure what results you're after/expecting but you could use `group by`. EG: `... GROUP BY projects.Project_ID;`

Comment: @Moob Then it only gives me two of the four answers
I.E. 'Timber', 'Brick Layer'

Comment: Grouping by material_name or job_name gives me 3 of the four results since one of the columns is always repeated. Ex: group by job name gives this: http://imgur.com/nSN4FQa

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you *want* the result to look like?

Comment: Timber,Brick layer
(New row)
Bricks, Project manager

Comment: Material_name and job_name in separate columns with no repeated data as is currently happening

Comment: 1. Don't use comma join syntax. It's effectively been deprecated since the last milennium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this:

```
select m.Material_Name, s.JobName
    from project_materials pm 
    join materials m on pm.Fitting_ID = m.Fitting_ID 
        and pm.Project_ID = m.Project_ID
    join project_staff ps on pm.Project_ID = ps.Project_ID
    join staff_job_type sjt on ps.Staff_job_ID = sjt.Staff_job_ID
where pm.Project_ID = '2'
```

The above query is unusable, since materials has no Project_ID. Even if the columns is available in materials, the result is still double, not as expected. Please ignore it.

I think we need a column that relate a record on materials to record on staff_job_type, something like foreign key. Without that column, we will ended up in all-to-all relationship. Project_ID alone will not enough, because it is not unique for materials and staff_job_type. Column staff_job_id will relate staff_job_type with project_staff and column Fitting_ID will relate materials with project_material. No column relate materials with staff_job_type.

```
material_name job_name        sjt.staff_job_id ps.staff_job_id m.fitting_id pm.fitting_id  
------------- --------------- ---------------- --------------- ------------ ------------- 
Timber        Brick Layer     1                1               1            1           
Bricks        Brick Layer     1                1               2            2           
Timber        Project Manager 2                2               1            1           
Bricks        Project Manager 2                2               2            2
```

I suggest you to create a table to relate/map materials to staff_job_type. The table should be something like this:

```
create table material_job (
  fitting_id int,
  staff_job_id int
);
```

And the table is containing materials and staff_job_type relation:

```
fitting_id  staff_job_id 
----------- ------------ 
1           1            
2           2
```

with assumption that materials is like:

```
fitting_id  material_name                                      
----------- -------------------------------------------------- 
1           Timber                                             
2           Bricks
```

and staff_job_type is like

```
staff_job_id job_name                                           
------------ -------------------------------------------------- 
1            Brick Layer                                        
2            Project Manager
```

project_materials like

```
project_id  fitting_id  amount      
----------- ----------- ----------- 
2           1           500         
2           2           600
```

project_staff like

```
project_id  staff_job_id amount      
----------- ------------ ----------- 
2           1            100         
2           2            200
```

we can use query

```
select m.material_name, sjt.job_name from material_job mj
    join materials m on mj.fitting_id = m.fitting_id
    join staff_job_type sjt on mj.staff_job_id = sjt.staff_job_id;
```

resulting

```
material_name job_name                                           
------------- ---------------
Timber        Brick Layer                                        
Bricks        Project Manager
```

if you need project_staff and project_material record as well, we can use sql:

```
select m.material_name, sjt.job_name from material_job mj
    join materials m on mj.fitting_id = m.fitting_id
    join staff_job_type sjt on mj.staff_job_id = sjt.staff_job_id
    join project_materials pm on m.fitting_id = pm.fitting_id
    join project_staff ps on sjt.staff_job_id = ps.staff_job_id;
```

resulting

```
material_name job_name        pm_amount ps_amount      
------------- --------------- --------- ---------
Timber        Brick Layer     500       100                                                           
Bricks        Project Manager 600       200
```

Comment: materials (m) doesn't have project_ID.

Edited OP

Comment: oh sorry, does materials have a column that also exists in staff_job_type?

Comment: http://imgur.com/XSoflep is this snippet of my ER diagram explain the situation better?

Comment: Thanks gab, for providing your ERD, it really helps me to replicate the topic. I edited my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: The requirement said that it must be filtered via project_ID , and bypassing project_ID would thus go around the requirement and the results would not be organised via project but with worker

Comment: Your're right though, there is no way to filter it out without a direct link, so best answer was chosen